# Como abrir projetos no Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Baixei vários projetos prontos para fins de estudo no Android Studio. São projetos como calculadora, agenda, etc. Porém não consigo abrí-los no Android Studio da maneira que, julgo eu, seja correta. Consigo abrir arquivos separados, como por exemplo o xml... Mas não sei como abrir todo o projeto.

Em resumo, existe alguma maneira de abrir o projeto baixado assim como fazemos, por exemplo, no Visual Studio ao executar o arquivo .sln?

Por mais simples que seja, procurei bastante e tentei por conta diversas vezes, sem sucesso.

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Apesar da questão ser off-topic, vou tentar lhe dar uma dica, eu não uso o AndroidStudio, mas acredito que seja parecido com o Eclipse, após instalar o AndroidStudio, na pasta "Documentos" (no Windows) ou pasta do usuário (em sistemas like-unix seria algo como `/home/user/`) procure uma pasta chamada "AndroidProjects" cole as pastas dos projetos extraidas dentro dessa pasta, um projeto deve ficar algo como `./AndroidProjects/exemplo/` dentro desta pasta deve ter arquivos como `AndroidManifest.xml`, então ao abrir o AndroidStudio é possível que o projeto "exemplo" esteja listado.

Comment: Mesmo não achando que está fora do escopo, uma vez que não temos por enquanto a esperança de um `SUpt`, aqui vai minha resposta: da mesma forma que o Guilherme explicou, como no Eclipse, não é necessário um arquivo único que diz qual o projeto e independente de qual diretório esteja o seu projeto, se no Android Studio você ir em *"Open an existing Android Studio projet"*, basta apontar para a raiz desde que você baixou (o que possui os arquivos de *properties, iml*, diretórios *app, build* e etc). Neste caso, o arquivo *manifest* não fica aqui.

Comment: Para abrir o projeto se ele já for referente a um projeto Android Studio basta apenas ir em "Open.."  e selecionar o projeto. Até o icone fica no formato da logo do AS. Provavelmente alguns erros aparecerão devido a questão de versões, mas é só ir clicando nos erro e pedindo pro AS ir resolvendo (baixando e instalando).